# DataGrip - How to load all my columns as TEXT and How to load multiple files at the same time?

Tags: database, csv, loading, datagrip

I've recently started using DataGrip since my DBs are in different management systems -- makes it easy to have them one platform.
However, I've ran into several issues/challenges I just cannot find answers for.
Would anyone happen to know how:

- Change the settings such as, when loading data, every column is being imported as TEXT by default
  (don't want to change INT to TEXT and NUMERIC to TEXT most of the
  time)
- Import multiple CSVs at the same time: for e.g. import 'n' CSV files with the same settings vs import individually the CSV files one-by-one (which takes significantly more time).

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibilities like these for now.

1. I added your comment here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4917
2. Created a ticket, please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5277

Comment: Thanks for the help @moscas